# How to validate jwt token signature using certificate thumbprint in java?

Tags: java, authentication, jwt

There is 1 client (C1) and 2 servers (S1 and S2). Both servers have their own self-signed certificates and have published their respective certificate thumbprint such that one can access the thumbprint of another. C1 interacts with S1 and gets a JWT token signed by S1's self-signed certificate. Now C1 interacts with S2 using the JWT token it received from S1. How does S2 validate the signature of the JWT token using the thumbprint of S1 in Java?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found out that it's not possible to validate signature using thumbprint. The public key only can do the job. So instead of or in addition to sharing thumbprints the two servers (S1 and S2) will have to publish the public key as well which will be used for JWT token signature.

Comment: this is correct. you can use a thumbprint to validate the integrity of a (public) key, but it's insufficient for signature verification.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

You have two servers, if you want to keep the status of the Token consistent in the two servers, it is recommended to use middleware nosql to store the user's status in the database. It is recommended to use redis (fast response, kv structure is enough to deal with your situation), and store the login information in redis. Then add a layer of filter to redis when the user requests to obtain the status, if not, to generate the token stored in redis, if there is a direct release and parse the Token to get the user's information